# combining three Strings containing CSV into a single list in android

Tags: android, csv

I have three strings as mentioned below

```
String1="1,2,3,4";
String2="5,6,7,8";
String3="2,4";
```

Now I want to combine these three strings into a single list so that the list looks somewhat like this:

```
1,5,2
2,6,4
3,7
4,8
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this would work or not but try this two step process :-

**Step 1 - Combine the strings**

```
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();

for(String tempString:setInput){
   sb.append(",").append(tempString).append(",");   
}
```

**Step 2 - Convert the string array to list**

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
```

Comment: @IT Team : if you have less no. of strings then for combining u can use `String s4=s1.concat(","+s2).concat(","+s3);`